# How to obtain a logarithmic voltage signal from a current using an op-amp and transistor in LTspice?

Tags: transistors, ltspice

I'm trying to model a circuit in LTspice where I obtain a logarithmic voltage signal from a current input using an op-amp and a transistor. I'm trying to get the sub-threshold operation of the transistor, which gives a logarithmic relationship between the input current and the output voltage.

I'm struggling to find where and how to model the sub-threshold slope (or the weak inversion slope) of the transistor in LTspice. Does anyone know how to incorporate this into the model? The image shows the setup of the circuit.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: I think you’re using the wrong transistor type. The concept of inversion applies to MOSFETs and not BJTs. Also one of your transistor terminals is floating.